# syntax error in select from where mysql statement

Tags: python, mysql

I got an syntax error in this code:

```
msql=("SELECT FILE_NAME FROM file_processed WHERE FILE_NAME = %s ;")

if cursor.execute(msql,name):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

i got an error near '%s'
can anybody tell me wherE? thanks!

error: 
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064(42000): You have an error in SQL syntax: check Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1 Im using mysql 5.6

Now I try this:

```
msql=("SELECT FILE_NAME FROM file_processed WHERE FILE_NAME='HCTC3153_INF.TXT'; ")
if cursor.execute(msql):
    print "its is in the db"
    return True
else:
    print "its not in db"
    return False
```

Always return its not in db even is in there...
The error raise now is:
 raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found.")
 mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found.

Comment: You should show us the error message and the traceback.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064(42000): You have an error in SQL syntax: check Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1 Im using mysql 5.6

Comment: Now try removing the ; As far as I remember it ok for editors, not for db api

Comment: @Kein-Wai I checked it in my machine and it fails when I use semi-colon at the end. Also please show where and how you are substituting the values using %s. That would help identify the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I assume you are using %s for string formatting and not just a file with name %s.

I think you need to use '%s', not %s as in

```
msql=("SELECT FILE_NAME FROM file_processed WHERE FILE_NAME ='%s'")
```

Sorry if I misunderstood the use of %s completely

Comment: Wow! an instant -1!! Whoever did it, it would help a lot for me to learn from my mistake if you also gave a reason for down-voting it.

Comment: It's down-voted because it's wrong, simple as that. You don't quote values when you use parameter substitution with the db API.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. But my logic is simply that we are creating a query and executing it. Normally if I write the same query to check for file names like FILE1, I would specify the query as "FILE_NAME LIKE 'FILE1'", not "FILE_NAME LIKE FILE1"

Comment: But where are you (and Sundar) getting this idea that OP wants to do a LIKE query? That has nothing to do with the question asked or the error he is getting.

Comment: Sorry I had initially thought it is = but changed seeing above answer, my bad. My correct comments: Normally if I write the same query to check for file with name FILE1, I would specify the query as "FILE_NAME ='FILE1'", not "FILE_NAME = FILE1". So if you are using %s for substitution, dont we still need quotes?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I did some research. Thanks for helping me learn that we dont need quotes for db api. But using quotes it still works for me. So I guess I am not wrong, just that what I did was unneeded :)

Answer (score 0):

msql=("SELECT FILE_NAME FROM file_processed WHERE FILE_NAME LIKE '%s'")

try this dnt need to put ; near %s

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064(42000): You have an error in SQL syntax: check Mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1
Im using mysql 5.6

Comment: still giving me the error. i think is the way it treats %s...not sure why

Comment: u query is in the typo error normally if u use wildcards % are only applicable in LIKE-queries.

Comment: Argh, so much wrongness. %s is a substitution parameter, nothing to do with like queries.

Comment: I have no idea what that comment means. As I said to haraprasadj, there is nothing in the question to indicate OP is trying to do a LIKE query. He is simply trying to use parameter substitution to insert the value of a variable into the query.

Comment: @Daniel IMHO he is not trying to insert in this line msql=("SELECT FILE_NAME FROM file_processed WHERE FILE_NAME = %s ;") he is getting a error as server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at the line he is missing LIKE operator as well as '   ' in %s

Comment: @Daniel he should have put that variable definition too.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
enter code here
```

[image]

got this!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first error, which I assume looks like:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s'

Is because `cursor.execute()` expects a tuple in the second argument, as explained by @mata [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070368/use-parameterized-query-with-mysql-connector-in-python-2-7/40070500#40070500). In your case, your code should be `cursor.execute(mysql,(name,))` - notice the comma after `name`.

I think you're receiving your second error:

> mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

because you aren't doing anything with the result. If you added a `result = cursor.fetchall()` in your `if` block your code should work.